# uploading csv with gdata - Content-Length error

Tags: android, gdata-api, google-docs-api

I'm attempting to use the gdata project from an android app. I'm attempting to upload a new csv file to google docs, but I keep encountering a 411 error (Content-Length).
 My code looks something like:

```
GoogleService ss = new SpreadsheetService("testApp");
ss.setUserCredentials("<username>", "<password>");

DocumentListEntry newEntry = null;
newEntry = new DocumentListEntry();
newEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("my.csv"));
TextConstruct tc = TextConstruct.plainText("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");         
newEntry.setContent(new TextContent(tc));

DocumentListEntry res = ss.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"), newEntry);
```

Since the GData lib is abstracting the network calls from me I assume that I don't need to set the Content-Length myself, which leads to me believe I'm simply not using the lib correctly.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about GData - there is no need to add `\n` at the end of the file / contents, right? I would suspect the TextConstruct class to be the problem here..

Answer (score 1):

The content of the file should not be set in the metadata but sent along the metadata using an HTTP multipart request.
The client library takes care of doing that and you can set the content using:

```
newEntry.setFile(/* java.io.File instance */ file, /* MIME type */ "text/csv");
```

This requires to load the data from a file, but you can use streams to load from memory.
A more detailed example can be [found](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/docs/DocumentList.java#443) in the Java client library project page.